# How to slice list based on a condition that every element of another list must appear atleast once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, slice

I have two lists :

```
a = [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 0]
key = [1, 2, 4, 6]
```

I want to check if all elements in the `key` have atleast once appeared in the list `a` and remove the ones after that.

desired output :

```
a = [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2]
```

here is what i tried:

```
if a[-1] not in key:
        indx = -1
        while indx < 0:
            
            if a[indx] in k:
                ind = indx
                indx = 1
            else: indx= indx-1
            
        a = a[:ind+1]
```

but this just check if the last element of `a` is in `key`. Idk how to check for the condition if all the key elements have appeared atleast once. Can some help ?

Comment: Are elements in `key` unique and always present in `a`?

Comment: yes all key elements are unique and always present in the a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an efficient solution that is O(n) and doesn't require slicing lists or a `list.index` operation in a loop:

First, create a dictionary mapping each element of `a` to the index of its *first* occurrence.

```
a = [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 0]

a_lookup = dict()
for ind, val in enumerate(a):
    if val not in a_lookup: 
        a_lookup[val] = ind
```

This gives us

```
a_lookup = {3: 0, 8: 1, 5: 2, 1: 3, 4: 4, 7: 5, 6: 8, 2: 10, 0: 15}
```

Next, find the largest value in the dictionary, for all keys in the `key` list. If we use `dict.get` to get the keys, a non-existent key will return `None`, which will cause a TypeError in the `max` call. We can catch this and handle it appropriately. Once we've found the maximum index, slice the list until this index to get what we need.

```
key = [1, 2, 4, 6]

try:
    max_index = max(a_lookup.get(k) for k in key)
    sliced_list = a[:max_index+1]
except TypeError:
    print("Error: all keys do not exist in a")
```

which gives,

```
sliced_list = [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function slices the list based on the condition that every element of the key must appear at least once in a.

```
def slice_list(a, key):
    for i in range(len(a)):  # iterate over the list
        if a[i] in key:  # check if the element is in the key
            key.remove(a[i])  # remove the element from the key
        if not key:  # if the key is empty
            return a[: i + 1]  # return the sliced list
    return a  # if the key is not empty return the original list


print(slice_list(a, key))


Output: [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
a = [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 0]
key = [1, 2, 4, 6]

max_idx = max(a.index(k) for k in key)
print(a[: max_idx + 1])
```

Prints:

```
[3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to get the same result :)

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if all(x in a[:i] for x in key):
        b = a[:i]
        break
print(b)
Output: [3, 8, 5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2]
```